# didn't work mysqli_query inside the class function but it work correctly outside the class

Tags: php, class, mysqli, pagination

I am working pagination in my project. My mysqli_query worked properly on outside the class but didn't work inside the class function.. Refer getTotalRows() in my code. Help me friends..

```
<?php

include('config_session.php');

// Here is my query is ececute successfully.

echo $result = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_subcategory order by subcat_pos ") or die("failed");

class CSSPagination
{
    private $totalrows;
    private $rowsperpage;
    private $website;
    private $page;
    private $sql;

    public function __construct($sql, $rowsperpage, $website)
    {


            $this->sql = $sql;

        $this->website = $website;
        $this->rowsperpage = $rowsperpage;
    }

    public function setPage($page)
    {
        if (!$page) { $this->page=1; } else  { $this->page = $page; }
    }

    public function getLimit()
    {
        return ($this->page - 1) * $this->rowsperpage;
    }

    private function getTotalRows()
    {

           // Here is my query is didn't execute. Only echo failed message

             $result = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_subcategory order by subcat_pos ") or die("failed");  



        $this->totalrows = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
    }

    private function getLastPage()
    {
        return ceil($this->totalrows / $this->rowsperpage);
    }

    public function showPage()
    {
        $this->getTotalRows();

        $pagination = "";
        $last = $this->getLastPage();
        $lpm1 = $this->getLastPage() - 1;
        $page = $this->page;
        $prev = $this->page - 1;
        $next = $this->page + 1;

        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\"";
        if($margin || $padding)
        {
            $pagination .= " style=\"";
            if($margin)
                $pagination .= "margin: $margin;";
            if($padding)
                $pagination .= "padding: $padding;";
            $pagination .= "\"";
        }
        $pagination .= ">";

        if ($this->getLastPage() > 1)
        {
            if ($page > 1) 
                $pagination .= "<a href=$this->website&page=$prev>« prev</a>";
            else
                $pagination .= "<span class=\"disabled\">« prev</span>";


            if ($this->getLastPage() < 9)
            {   
                for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $this->getLastPage(); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination .= "<span class=\"current\">".$counter."</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination .= "<a href=$this->website&page=$counter>".$counter."</a>";                 
                }
            }
            elseif($this->getLastPage() >= 9)
            {
                if($page < 4)       
                {
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 6; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination .= "<span class=\"current\">".$counter."</span>";
                        else
                            $pagination .= "<a href=$this->website&page=$counter>".$counter."</a>";                 
                    }
                    $pagination .= "...";
                    $pagination .= "<a href=$this->website&page=$lpm1>".$lpm1."</a>";
                    $pagination .= "<a href=$this->website&page=$last>".$last."</a>";       
                }
                elseif($last - 3 > $page && $page > 1)
                {
                    $pagination .= "<a href=$this->website&page=1>1</a>";
                    $pagination .= "<a href=$this->website&page=2>2</a>";
                    $pagination .= "...";
                    for ($counter = $page - 1; $counter <= $page + 1; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination .= "<span class=\"current\">".$counter."</span>";
                        else
                            $pagination .= "<a href=$this->website&page=$counter>".$counter."</a>";                 
                    }
                    $pagination .= "...";
                    $pagination .= "<a href=$this->website&page=$lpm1>$lpm1</a>";
                    $pagination .= "<a href=$this->website&page=$last>".$last."</a>";       
                }
                else
                {
                    $pagination .= "<a href=$this->website&page=1>1</a>";
                    $pagination .= "<a href=$this->website&page=2>2</a>";
                    $pagination .= "...";
                    for ($counter = $last - 4; $counter <= $last; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination .= "<span class=\"current\">".$counter."</span>";
                        else
                            $pagination .= "<a href=$this->website&page=$counter>".$counter."</a>";                 
                    }
                }
            }

        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination .= "<a href=$this->website&page=$next>next »</a>";
        else
            $pagination .= "<span class=\"disabled\">next »</span>";
        $pagination .= "</div>\n";          
        }   

        return $pagination;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: consider putting your code in a code block or neatening it. Very difficult to follow your snippet.

Comment: How are you calling your getTotalRows().

Comment: In `getTotalRows()` you are using an undefined variable `$conn` when making the query. Functions and methods don't have access to variables created in the global namespace or in other functions or methods. You need to pass the `$conn` variable to either the class constructor (and then use `$this->conn` like you did with `$sql`) or to the method itself.

Comment: @jeff$pagination = new CSSPagination($sql1, $rowsperpage, $website); 
$pagination->setPage($_GET[page]);

Comment: @Magnus Erikssson   $conn is my connection variable it may calling from config_session.php file..so already include that file in top of the page.

Comment: Please read my comment again. Specifically: *Functions and methods don't have access to variables created in the global namespace or in other functions or methods.*

Comment: @Magnus Erikssson   Oh sorry...I understood wrongly..Now it execute. But  it didn't show anything.

Comment: I have no idea what it suppose to show since we don't know where or how you're calling what method, or even where you instantiate the class. It seems like another question though, since you solved what the title of this question mentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$conn is replaced by this->$conn

Now it works fine ... Thank you friends